# AWS CodeBuild Git Connection - Only Refresh Updated Code

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm using AWS to package my node10.x lambda code & dependencies for my site. I have my git repos broken out by function - so I have a repo dedicated to my rest-auth lambdas as an example (I'm still actively developing this, so there are pleanty of missing buildspec & function files).

My git repo has the following layout:

```
.
├── buildspec
│   ├── postmark.yml
│   ├── rest-auth-login.yml
│   ├── rest-auth-password-link.yml
│   └── rest-auth-register.yml
├── function_code
│   ├── login.js
│   ├── password-link.ext
│   ├── postmark.js
│   ├── register.js
│   └── rgistration-confirm.js
├── .gitignore
└── README.md
```

Right now when I push an update to github all 4 buildspec configs fire and create 4 zip files in my S3 bucket for my lambdas to read from.

However, all 4 zip files are recreated even if there are only changes to ONE of their underlying code -- I know I can split each function into it's own repo, but is there a way to configure AWS CodeBuild to only trigger updates for a given buildspec if specific files are changed in the repo?

Ie only run the `postmark.yml` if the `postmark.js` file is changed?

Example `postmark.yml`

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 10  
    commands:
      - npm install postmark
artifacts:
  files:
    - 'function_code/postmark.js'
    - 'node_modules/**/*'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can use the "file_path" option to only trigger when the specific file is changed as described in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-github-pull-request.html#sample-github-pull-request-filter-webhook-events-console

Adding the following to the ource of the postmark build will result in that build only triggering when the postmark.js file is updated
[image]